# Kill a hanging Process from Scala

Tags: scala, process

My code has to call some external programs which sometimes hangs. (endless loop, will never return)

To start the external Process i use:

```
import tools.nsc.io.Process
val res = Process("ls")
res.foreach(println)
res.waitFor // waits until a Process is finished but if it's hanging waitFor will not return or
res.destroy // kills a process
```

But i didn't find a way to check if the process is still running. Or a waitFor(time) so that i only wait for some time.

I believe their should be a simple solution but i'm not able to find it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see method `exitValue` in `Process` is defined as folows:

```
def exitValue(): Option[Int] =
    catching(classOf[IllegalThreadStateException]) opt process.exitValue()
```

So you can check whether `exitValue()` returns `None` or `Some` value. `None` means that process is still running. It follows from [documentation to Java `Process.exitValue()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue%28%29)